# Got a string, must call function which name correspond to that string

Tags: php

Here is the code

```
 foreach ( $form as $fieldName => $fieldValue ) {
            $validationType = $validationCriterias[ $fieldName ] ?? null;

            if ( $validationType ) { // is  "username" at that point
                call_user_func( $validationType );
            }
        }

function username( )
{
    global $form;
    if ( ! v::alnum( '-_' )->noWhitespace()->length( 2, 30 )->validate( $form[ 'username' ] ) ) {
        $this->formErrorBag[ 'username' ] = 'User name must be between 2 and 30 characters please. No whitespace or special charactesr allowed, but "_" and "-" characters are allowed.';
    }
}
```

In this code, where indicated in the loop, I have a string "username" is $validationType.
Then, I need to call the function username which is below the loop.

I tried to use the call_user_func, but it gives this error:

> 'call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function
>   'username' not found or invalid function name'

What is the proper way to call username() from string "username" ?

EDIT: this code is already in a class method, so if possible, i would need to access username() scope from inside the loop.

Comment: is username() function in the same scope of this foreach() ? Because if $validationType is really username at that point, username should be called. they are in a class or different files ?

Comment: exactly, username() is in same scope as foreach() which are both inside a class method.

Comment: I think function username shoudn't be inside another method, and that's why call_user_func() isn't finding it. The bnest would be refactor, putting username as another method outside your current method, and using $this->$validationType() instead.

Comment: this is what I ended up using and it works. Please post it as an answer so I can choose it.

Comment: glad to know it worked. Posted as answer =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comments, your function username() shoudn't be inside another method. That's why call_user_func() isn't finding it.

The best way is to refactor the code, putting username as another method, so you'll be able to call it as `$this->$validationType()`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your functions are in a class, so, any functions that you want to call need to be like $this->nameOfTheFunction().

To call your function you can do:
**$this->$validationType()** or **call_user_func( $this->$validationType() )**

Comment: actually all this code is in a method, so I can't use this. I can refactor code of course, but isn't there anyway to access username() outside of the scope of the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a function I'm pretty sure you have to use the `()` behind it, in your code you are only using the name. You might try something like:

```
if ( $validationType. "()" ) { // is  "username" at that point
        call_user_func( $validationType. "()" );
    }
```

This is untested but might work.

Answer (score 0):

Your's functions has to be in same namespace, then u can test for callable

---

```
$validators = ['username', 'surname', 'NotAFunction'];

foreach($validators as $func)
    if(is_callable($func))
        $func();


function username(){
     echo 'validation username' . PHP_EOL;
}

function surname(){
     echo 'validation surname' . PHP_EOL;
}
```